# what happens when expansion parameter is of the order of dynamical variable itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Lets consider following differential equation,

$\epsilon \frac{dy}{dt} = ....$

In principle one can use Method of matched asymptotic expansion or Method of multiple scales to solve such singular problems. But these techniques work on inherent assumption on $\epsilon \ll 1$ or more precisely $\epsilon \ll \frac{dy}{dt}$ for all times.

Now if in some time domain the later condition is not satisfied, the standard expansion breaksdown. What is the remedy to deal with such problems?

Comment: If $dy/dt$ is very small, why not just neglect the left hand side of the equation?